# Covert integer in pattern (1>=5, 6>=10, 11>=15 ...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, int

I have no idea to covert int like `1>=5, 6>=10, 11>=15` ...

I don't know how this call, but I think this example will explain my question...

```
1 = 5
2 = 5
3 = 5
4 = 5
5 = 5
6 = 10
7 = 10
8 = 10
9 = 10
10 = 10
11 = 15
//and more..
```

So JS

```
var x = 1;
var result = (???) // 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Math.floor((x-1)/5 + 1) * 5
```

Simpler version (@RichardTowers):

```
Math.ceil(x/5) * 5
```

Comment: `Math.ceil(x/5) * 5` ?

Comment: Ok thanks , what about `1>=10 11>=20` (ending with 0) ? and '0>=3, 4>=13, 14>=23' (ending with 3)

Comment: `Math.ceil(x/10)*10` or `x+10-x%10`

Comment: just `Math.ceil(x/y) * y` @RobertMcKee ?

Comment: Yes, `Math.ceil(x/y)*y` or `x+y-x%y`

Comment: The answer for the 'ending with 3 pattern' is: `Math.ceil((x-3)/10)*10 + 3`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

```
var x=1;
var change= numberChange(x);
function numberChange(x){
    while(x%5!=0){
        x=x+1;
    }
    return x;
}
alert(change);
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srsMM/)